# What is the notation that can be reduced to f(b)-f(a) called?

Tags: functions, notation

This is from page 57 of The Theoretical Minimum, I'm not sure what this notation is called and I'd like to be able to write it in Mathjax.

[image: notation]

Comment: \left . x\; \sin x \right|_0^{\pi/2} produces  $\left . x\; \sin x \right|_0^{\pi/2}$

Comment: Not sure it has a name but "x\sin x \big |_{0}^{\pi/2}" renders as $x\sin x \big |_{0}^{\pi/2}$.

Comment: Is a common notation and IMHO not have a name: you are definitely calculating an integral defined between the upper extreme $\pi/2$ and $0$ of the primitive.

Comment: *Ultimately*, this is just a special case of the Gauß-Ostrogradsky theorem. That would suggest something like "surface integral over the interval boundary", but such a word monster  is certainly never used for this

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, this notation has no particular name.  If I were reading it out loud, I would read $$f(x) \big|_{a}^{b}$$ as "the difference between $f$ evaluated at $b$ and $f$ evaluated at $a$" or "the change in $f$ over the interval $[a,b]$" or something similar.